# Redirect page if PDO database update is success

Tags: php, pdo

Here is a part of the code I am using to update the database.
It works, but I would like to  redirect the user to another page if the database update is a success.
How can I do that ?
I know the     `header('Location: ../../');`, but where to use it ?

```
$statement = $dbconnect->prepare("
   UPDATE members 
   SET name = :fname, lastname = :lname, phone = :phone 
   WHERE member_id = :memberid
");
$dbconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement->execute(
   array(
      ':fname' => "$fname", 
      ':lname' => "$lname", 
      ':phone' => "$phone",
      ':memberid' => "$memberid"
   )
);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Even tried the following, but no redirection

```
    $statement->execute(array(':fname' => "$fname", ':lname' => "$lname", ':phone' => "$phone",':memberid' => "$memberid"));

if ($statement) {
   header('Location: http://sitename.com');
} else {
   echo 'It failed!';
}
```

Comment: Make sure you enable all error reporting. It's possible there's an error being thrown (not in the query but possibly in sending the header) you're not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the result from the `PDOStatement::execute` execution and use the correct binding when you execute a prepared statement with an array of insert values (named parameters). Note, that the result from the successful `PDO::prepare` call is a  `PDOStatement` object, not a boolean value.

The folloling script, based on your code, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php

try {

    $dbconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = $dbconnect->prepare("
        UPDATE members 
        SET name = :fname, lastname = :lname, phone = :phone 
        WHERE member_id = :memberid
    ");
    if ($statement === false) {
       die("ERROR: Could not prepare statement.");
    }

    $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':fname' => $fname, 
            ':lname' => $lname, 
            ':phone' => $phone,
            ':memberid' => $memberid
        )
    );
    if ($result) {
        header('Location: http://sitename.com');    
        exit;
    }   
    
} catch(PDOException $e) {

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());

}

?>
```

Comment: I will try it and reply, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assume that your update was successful as long as you did not encounter any PDO errors (I assume that updates without errors are successful) you can write this:

```
$statement = $dbconnect->prepare("UPDATE members SET name = :fname, lastname = :lname, phone = :phone WHERE member_id = :memberid");
$dbconnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement->execute(array(':fname' => "$fname", ':lname' => "$lname", ':phone' => "$phone",':memberid' => "$memberid"));

// if there were no errors redirect now
header('Location: ../../');


   } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

On another note outside of dev you should find a different way to handle the error: this is almost the same as not having a try/catch.

Comment: no, that did t work, that was the first thing I tried even before asking this question here. The data gets saved, there is no error. but redirection not happening.

Comment: If it is not redirecting what is happening instead? White screen? Others are on to something: check your error log. Also change your catch to catch(Throwable $e) that way any error will show up in your die()

Comment: I used javascript to redirect, the results are showing correctly. But I dont know why PHP redirection didn't work!

Comment: I am trying to imagine what might be happening. Set the redirect to Google or StackOverflow.com and see if that fires. If you are submitting this form using AJAX it will not redirect: AJAX calls do not refresh the web page and the redirect will not work. That would explain why your database is updating but the page is not redirecting. Look at the network tab of Chrome and that will tell you what is happening. If you want the page to redirect after the form submits do a regular HTML form submission instead of JavaScript and the page will redirect as you expect.